# Show that $\mathbb{P}(A\vert B)=\mathbb{E}(1_{A}\vert B)$.

Tags: probability

Show that $\mathbb{P}(A\vert B)=\mathbb{E}(1_{A}\vert B)$.

I know that $\mathbb{P}(A\vert B)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$, any help!!

Comment: Are you going to post offshoots of offshoots of the same and unique question you have problems with, forever? For episode n-1, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681532/.

Answer (score 2):

By definition :

$$\mathbb E[1_A\mid B]=1\cdot \mathbb{P}\{A\mid B\}+0\cdot \mathbb{P}\{A^c\mid B\}=\mathbb{P}\{A\mid B\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$1_A$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ and $P(1_A=1\mid B)=P(A\mid B)$.